# How To Use Multiple Nodejs Server Communication

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io. Let say I have two node js server and both of them are behind a loadbalancer. Player A connects to Nodejs A server. After a few hours, Player B connects to Nodejs B server. Player B is Player A friend. I want to let Player A know that his friend is online. Also, how can I get them both join the same poker game?

- Here are my questions:

  1. For Player A, to know his friend is online. So, I should create a method that checks Nodejs B if one of his friends is logged in to another server. Can I do this using [Mutliple Node](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/)? If so, can anyone give me an idea of how this works?
  2. How can I implement socket.join(room[, callback]) if the other player in login to another server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe look into something like [Colyseus](https://colyseus.io/#features).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a [Redis adapter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) that will facilitate communication between your socket.io server instances.

I am not sure what load balancing you are using, but using the above in combination with sticky sessions will do the trick. See the section on [using multiple nodes](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) for example configurations for common proxies/load balancers.

Comment: thanks! On the git hub link, it says "By running socket.io with the socket.io-redis adapter you can run multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other." so this mostly what I am looking for. But I am still new to this so I shall read more about it.